# How to calculate points on a line relative to their rectangular containers?

Tags: geometry

[image]

Given 2 rectangles with known widths and heights of w1, h1 and w2, h2, and a connecting straight line from the centers of each rectangle, with known starting point x1,y1, and known ending point x2,y2, how can I calculate the points on the line where it passes the edge of each rectangle (as defined by x1a,y1a, and x2a,y2a)?

EDIT:
Adding some simple Javascript code to render the 2 rectangles, the line, and plot the point for (x1a, y1a).

```
let x1 = 75;
let y1 = 40;

let x2 = 375;
let y2 = 340;

let w1 = 150;
let h1 = 80;

let w2 = 150;
let h2 = 80;

// Create objects
let objects = document.getElementById("objects");

let rect1 = document.createElement("div");
rect1.classList.add("rect");
rect1.style.top = "0px";
rect1.style.left = "0px";
rect1.style.width = `${w1}px`;
rect1.style.height = `${h1}px`;

objects.appendChild(rect1);

let rect2 = document.createElement("div");
rect2.classList.add("rect");
rect2.style.width = `${w2}px`;
rect2.style.height = `${h2}px`;
rect2.style.top = "300px";
rect2.style.left = "300px";

objects.appendChild(rect2);

// Insert the path
let line = document.createElementNS(
  "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
  "path"
);

line.setAttribute("stroke", "#000");
line.setAttribute("fill", "none");
line.setAttribute("stroke-width", "2");
line.setAttribute("d", `M${x1},${y1} ${x2},${y2}`);

document.getElementById("svg").appendChild(line);

// Update the point

let x1a = x1 - ((h1 / 2) * (x2 - x1)) / (y2 - y1);

let point1 = document.createElement("div");
point1.classList.add("point");

// y coordinate of the point is just the height of the rectangle given it crosses
// the bottom edge of the rectangle
point1.style.top = `${h1}px`;

point1.style.left = `${x1a}px`;
objects.appendChild(point1);
```

The point does not show up in the right position, as it has the wrong x1a co-ordinate.

Screenshot of rendering (blue dot is the x1a, y1a point):
[image]

Comment: Take one point to be the origin and then write equations of lines, points etc.

Comment: What are the correct equations to write to get x1a,y1a and x2a,y2a? That's what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: As you have two points’ coordinates, you must also know where the origin is?

Answer (score 1):

The equation of the line connecting the two centers is

$$(x_2-x_1) y-(y_2-y_1)x=y_1x_2-x_1y_2$$

Then, for the case in the diagram, substitute $y=y_{1a}= y_1-\frac{h_1}2$ and $y=y_{2a}=y_2+\frac{h_2}2$ to obtain the respective

$$x_{1a}=x_1 -\frac{h_1}2 \frac{x_2-x_1}{y_2-y_1}, \>\>\>\>\>
 x_{2a}=x_2 +\frac{h_2}2 \frac{x_2-x_1}{y_2-y_1} $$

(Note that there are four cases to consider depending on the relative sizes of the widths and heights.)

Comment: I can't seem to get that equation for x1a to work. Here is an example showing the attempt to plot the x1a, y1a point using that equation: https://codepen.io/theericanderson/pen/MWjvzMy

I must be getting something wrong here.

Comment: @Eric - I am unable to read your codes in the link. Could provide the update in the post

Comment: @ quanto I just updated the main post with my implementation.